# 'was supposed to' gives the result?

Tags: past-tense

When we wanna say intention we had in the past, we say

> I was supposed to go to church at the time.

Instead of 'was supposed to', phrases like 'was about to','was meant to', 'would', etc can go between subject and verb with a bit different meanings.

But **for all those cases**, if there's nothing given about context and time reference, does that sentence imply their intention(to verb) is done after saying that ?

Or does it only means the intention the subject had at that moment, whatever happens after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no, in most cases you cannot make the assumption that the actor performed the intended action. As you say, the different phrases may imply a greater likelihood that the action happened; but by themselves, they still leave the question open. By saying, "I was supposed to go to church", the implication is that the sentence would be followed with something like, "..., but I stayed home instead." However, ending it like this is fine, too: "..., and I did, but I just couldn't focus on what the pastor had to say."